# How to automatically scroll up a wicket panel when wicket feedbackpanel is trigged?

Tags: java, jquery, focus, wicket, feedbackpanel

Im using a FeedbackPanel to show errormessage during validation controlls in a wicket form.
When the message occurs it occur in the top of the form(page). And my problem is that I might scrolled down when making a input and than I cant see the errormessage if I dont croll the form to the top of the page.
I would like to know how I can set the focus on the feedbackpanel so that everytime a errormessage is shown the form scrolls to the top automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use ajax-submit?

Then you can add a javascript / jQuery to the `AjaxRequestTarget`. For example this:

```
String myScript = " $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#ELEMENT_ID').offset().top - 20}, 'slow');";
ajaxRequestTarget.appendJavascript(myScript);
```

Where you need to set the `#ELEMENT_ID` to your form.

Or alternatively, if you set a `HTML` `ANCHOR` (#)

```
function scrollTo(hash) {
    location.hash = "#" + hash;
}
```